# The problem with the field is the type of which is another class

Tags: java, spring, converters

I created a field that is converted into another class, through which I get json, where the problem occurs, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong

`User` class

```
public class User extends BaseEntity<Integer> {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  @Column(name = "username")
  private String username;
  @Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
  private PurshasedProductConverter purshasedProducts;
}
```

`PurshasedProductConverter` class

```
public class PurshasedProductConverter implements AttributeConverter<PurshasedProduct, String> {

  private static final Logger LOG = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(PurshasedProductConverter.class);

  private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(PurshasedProduct attribute) {
    try {
        if (attribute != null)
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(attribute);
        else
        return null;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public PurshasedProduct convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef
            = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {
    };

    try {
        PurshasedProduct purshasedProduct = new PurshasedProduct();
        if (dbData != null)
            purshasedProduct.strings = mapper.readValue(dbData, typeRef);
        return purshasedProduct;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

`PurshasedProduct` class

```
public class PurshasedProduct {

  public Map<String, String> strings = new HashMap<>();

  public static PurshasedProduct create(String key, String value) {
    PurshasedProduct purshasedProduct = new PurshasedProduct();
    purshasedProduct.set(key, value);
    return purshasedProduct;
  }

  public void set(String lang, String text) {
    if (text == null || lang == null) {
        return;
    }
    strings.put(lang, text);
  }

  public String get(String lang) {
    if (lang == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (strings.containsKey(lang)) {
        return strings.get(lang);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void remove(String lang) {
    if (lang == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (strings.containsKey(lang)) {
        strings.remove(lang);
    }
  }

  public Set<String> getLangs() {
    return strings.keySet();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;

    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    PurshasedProduct that = (PurshasedProduct) o;

    return CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(strings.entrySet(), that.strings.entrySet());
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "PurshasedProduct{" +
            "products=" + strings +
            '}';
  }
}
```

When building the application, no error occurs, an error occurs when I try to enter the admin. Here are the logs :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not set field value [PurshasedProduct{products={}}] value by reflection : [class ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts] setter of ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [PurshasedProduct{products={}}] value by reflection : [class ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts] setter of ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.findByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at ru.valyaeva.marathon.auth.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at ru.valyaeva.marathon.auth.AuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationTokenFilter.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set ru.valyaeva.marathon.utils.PurshasedProductConverter field ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.User.purshasedProducts to ru.valyaeva.marathon.model.PurshasedProduct
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    ... 100 common frames omitted
```

Comment: this is the main problem. check where you use the wrong type, and adjust your code: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set aa.utils.PurshasedProductConverter field aa.model.User.purshasedProducts to aa.model.PurshasedProduct

Comment: this is all code

Comment: Do you understand what that error message says?

Comment: i use this type in user model

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: It's the same problem as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219697/java-reflection-can-not-set-error?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look:

```
@Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
private PurshasedProductConverter purshasedProducts;
```

You used `PurshasedProductConverter` in annotation and field type as well. You should change it to field type which are you converting from/to in `PurshasedProductConverter`.

```
@Convert(converter = PurshasedProductConverter.class)
private PurshasedProduct purshasedProducts;
```

Comment: Ask your self this question: How do you want to obtain `PurshasedProduct` value from your `User` class, if you have `PurshasedProductConverter` object type instead of `PurshasedProduct`?

Comment: PurshasedProductConverter get PurshasedProduct

Comment: It doesn't work in this way. You used `@Converter` annotation with the class which implements a suitable interface. It's enough information for spring to do reflection based stuff to convert this object in the background when you save/fetch this entity to/from a database.